# spring data paging and composite key, hibernate unknow a field

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use IdClass for some entities

could not resolve property: samplingYear of: com.lcm.model.Samples

```
public class SamplingsPK implements Serializable {

    private int year; 
    private Integer id;

    public SamplingsPK(int year, Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.year=year;
    }
    ..
}


public class SamplesPK implements Serializable {

    private SamplingsPK sampling;
    private String sampleLetter;

    public SamplesPK(SamplingsPK sampling, String sampleLetter) {
        this.sampling = sampling;
        this.sampleLetter = sampleLetter;
    }
    ...
}

@Entity
@IdClass(SamplesPK.class)
public class Samples {
    @Id
    private String sampleLetter;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_year", referencedColumnName = "year")})
    private Samplings sampling;
    ....
}

@Entity
@IdClass(SamplingsPK.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Samplings {
    @Id
    private Integer year;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    ...
}
```

When I run this query

```
@Query(
  value = "select s from Samples s Join fetch s.sampling sp Join  fetch sp.machine m Join  fetch sp.product p Join  fetch p.productType",
  countQuery = "select count(s) from Samples s Join s.sampling sp Join  sp.machine m Join  sp.product p Join  p.productType")
    public Page<Samples> findAllFullSample(Pageable pageable);
```

and Pageable contain for these 3  fields

- samplingYear
- samplingId
- sampleLetter

I get

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: samplingYear
>   of: com.lcm.model.Samples

In samples, I have Samplings class so I need to pass by object name to access Year and Id...

Why this field is unknow?

edit

If I use *id, year sampleLetter*

```
select 
    samples0_.sample_letter as sample_l1_20_0_,
    ....
from
        samples samples0_ 
    inner join
        samplings samplings1_ 
            on samples0_.sampling_id=samplings1_.id 
            and samples0_.sampling_year=samplings1_.year 
    order by
        samples0_.sampling_year asc,
        samples0_.sample_letter,
        samples0_.sampling_id,
        samples0_.sampling_year asc,
        samples0_.sample_letter asc limit ?
```

they add more field then I need in the order by...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why this field is unknown?

You didn't declare `samplingYear` anywhere. It only appears in the error message and in the description of the `Pageable` but neither in your entity nor in your id-classes.

Maybe you mean `sampling.year`?

Comment: habitually in spring data when you do a query you pass by the name

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but the name "samplingYear" is nowhere used in the code you posted. Attribute-path-names are always separated with a '.'. The only exception are AFAIK method names for derived queries, but that's just because "." is not a legal character in Java method names.